# Active Directory, allow USB access using computer name

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I created a Group Policy Object (GPO) which contains configuration settings related to using USB devices. How do I apply the configuration settings contained in the GPO to a computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please let me know if I am misunderstanding, but it sounds like you are trying to create a Group Policy Object (GPO) that restricts the ability to to read from and/or write to USB drives on Windows Domain Joined computers. You wrote that you already have a GPO. The next step is to determine if the settings you added to the GPO are Computer settings or User settings. The last step is to use Group Policy Management to "link" the GPO to the Active Directory Organizational Unit (OU) where the computers or users for which the settings in the GPO should apply.